# net use delete in batch if drive exists

Tags: batch-file, net-use

i would like setup script which can connect network drive like this:

```
net use v: /delete || EXIT /B 1
net use v: "\\vmware-hostservername\share Folder"
```

I need to cover two scenario.

1. Run test after restarting of PC (no disc v: available)
2. run test repeatedly. Disc v: already exists and need to be deleted and mapped again.

I cannot put it to the window startup, because there are timeouts for disconnecting and the mapping need to done before running the script, so it ensures the drive will be available (and not disconnected).

The scrip provided does not work after restarting PC because v: does not exists.  It need some modification like

```
if exists V: net use v: /delete || EXIT /B 1
```

I am not too familiar with batch syntax of above psedocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if the mapping exists

```
net use v: && (net use v: /delete /Y || exit /b 1)
```

It executes `net use v:` to show the information for the drive. Then it uses conditional execution operator `&&`, that is, execute the next command if the previous one was sucessful.

If the drive exists, then it just tries to remove the mapping and in this case the conditional execution operator `||` (execute the next command if the previous one failed) is used.

Comment: Is the `/Y` actually needed?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

Following will unmount drive `I` without printing anything on console and keeping `errorlevel` at 0.

```
net use I: /delete /Y > NUL 2>&1 || dir > NUL
```

**Detail:**

Though the accepted answer is correct but it raises the `errorlevel` if the drive was not mounted. Since I only wanted to check and unmount existing drive without changing errorlevel, I came up with the command above.

`net use I: /delete /Y` tries to unmount drive `I` right away whereas `> NUL 2>&1` redirects the output to `NUL` device (hiding it from console).

If unmount fails (mount not detected), conditional execution `||` starts where `dir > NUL` prints current directory content to `NUL` device (again printing nothing on console). This resets the errorlevel to 0.

Final result is that nothing gets printed on the console and errorlevel stays at 0.

**Source:**
https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html

```
Disconnect from a share and close all resources (undocumented)
 NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE /Y
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What's the purpose of the `/Y` ? I can't see this is a flag that means anything.

Comment: I have updated the answer with full documentation. `/Y` implicitly closes all open resources.